# SSRS Report grouping values on a table

Tags: mysql, sql, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2014

I'm executing a query and getting about 250 pages of data in my table but most of it (I guess my primary key "Contract") is the same value for many rows, Is there a way to group all my "contract" variable results into one row only?
[executed table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBXY8.png)

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zervl.png)

Comment: Are you saying you want to have the `Contract` to only show once? Add a parent group for the `Contract` from the details group.

Comment: Yes, I need to make 'Contract' just showing up once , adding as consequence the Actual cost, Name1, Name 2 , Project Mgr, and udGEACrev as one row, each on its column

Comment: it is possible to group all you contract results into one row. But what about the information like date and billing amount. They have to be aggregated in a function. 

Will it suffice if only one billing date is shown?

Comment: Or do what WEI_DBA suggested.

Answer (score 0):

WEI_DBA is correct. Right click the table in Visual Studio and click "Add Parent Group", and select your "contract" column. It should group them together.

Comment: I am using SSRS for the table and query using a database on my server

Comment: Do you mean report builder?

Comment: My apologies, I've only used VS to create reports - this link should give you steps on how to do it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-or-delete-a-group-in-a-data-region-report-builder-and-ssrs

Comment: Yes @JacobH  I meant report builder